# ranlib/ar in Mac OS gives me "has no symbols" warning

Tags: c, macos, unix, linker

I use a particular libary that has a few ways of compiling it (platform- and target-specific code) and, as a result, sometimes has entirely empty .c files in the archive; the code was simply #ifdef'd away. This is absolutely understood and not a bug at all: I want it this way. And on Linux, this is indeed not a problem at all. If it were a problem, the linker would catch it.

Yet ranlib/ar on Mac OS cannot be convinced to suppress the "has no symbols" warnings for these files.

Now, I'm an engineer and I want to run my compilation process absolutely warning-less. This is critical code that is going to be evaluated; if I have warnings, people will look at me funny. Is there perhaps something I've overlooked? Some command-line option?

Thanks,

KJ

Comment: In such a case you can use a `grep -v 'no symbols'` as a pragmatic way to silent this (since you know what you are doing).

Comment: I would love a solution to this as well. Also 'grep -v' is *not* an acceptable workaround. It assumes that I am running the build. If someone else clones the repo they shouldn't need to grep out warnings when building.

Answer (score 5):

*Finally*, newer versions of `ranlib` offer an option `-no_warning_for_no_symbols`, which is described in the `man` page as

> Don't warn about file that have no symbols.

(as included in Xcode 10.1). Unfortunately, `ar` hasn't got this option yet. But as the `man` page states

> running ranlib is completely equivalent to executing ‘ar -s’

therefore you probably can replace many (if not all) calls of `ar` by `ranlib`.

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities that come to mind are (1) always put some symbol in the library, even if it is a zero-length object.  (2) provide wrappers in the Makefile environment to ranlib/ar that filter the warnings out.  The other user/automated build don't need to explicitly use grep -v, it can be in a command you provide and substitute, eg:

```
AR = $(PROJECT_HOME)/bin/project-ar
RANLIB = $(PROJECT_HOME)/bin/project-ranlib
```